# Unable to add behaviorExtension in machine.config via c#

Tags: c#, biztalk, machine.config, btdf

My BizTalk application requires me to add a custom behaviorExtension to my machine.config file. I install my application via MSI, via BizTalk Deployment Framework (BTDF), so I would like this to be done programmatically as well.

Now I cannot seem to find a way to either list installed behaviors not edit them.

I have the following code, but after that I'm stuck.

```
        // Get the machine.config file.
        Configuration machineConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
        // Get the machine.config file path.
        ConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ConfigurationFileMap(machineConfig.FilePath);

        // Map the application configuration file to the machine 
        // configuration file.
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(configFile);

        ConfigurationSectionGroup svcModel = config.SectionGroups.Get("system.serviceModel");
        ConfigurationSection extensions = svcModel.Sections.Get("extensions");
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Your `extensions` variable is of type `System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ExtensionsSection`, which has property BehaviorExtensions containing what you are looking for. So:

```
var extensions = (System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ExtensionsSection) svcModel.Sections.Get("extensions");
var behaviors = extensions.BehaviorExtensions;
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! I had no idea. Thank you.